# Oracle procedure to update values of one table to another another table field

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have two tables with two attributes.I have written a procedure which should take valuesfrom table1 and update it in Table 2.

```
MEDICINE 

BARCODE varchar2 13 byte
PDF_KUB_PATH  varchar2 1000 byte

PARSED_ILAC_REHBERI

BARCODE varchar2 13 byte
PDF_KUB_PATH  varchar2 1000 byte
```

This is my procedure in PL/SQL, i cant find where is my mistake, thanks in advance

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Deneme
IS
    BARCODETEMP VARCHAR2(13 BYTE);
    S_KUB VARCHAR2 (1000 BYTE);

    CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT a.PDF_KUB_PATH, a.BARCODE
    FROM medicine b,parsed_ilac_rehberi a
    WHERE a.BARCODE = b.barcode;
BEGIN

    OPEN c1;
    LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO  S_KUB , BARCODETEMP,

    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

    UPDATE medicine
    SET PDF_KUB_PATH = S_KUB
    WHERE BARCODE = BARCODETEMP; 

    END LOOP;

    CLOSE c1;

    COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'An error was encountered - '
                                    ||SQLCODE||' -ERROR'||SQLERRM);
end;
```

Comment: Do you get any errors or data is not getting updated correctly? Can you add more information to your question related to your issue

Comment: Don't you think it would help to tell us where/what the error is?

Comment: PROCEDURE Deneme compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning this is the message what i get, but when i look in my medicine table the field is just null. it is not updating.

Comment: your procedure name in the error (upddate_sorid_2) and your question  above (Deneme) doesn't match.

Comment: i tried in different names , different things, it was copy paste error sorry @rs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to use a procedure, you can solve your question just with sql script.

```
update medicine m
   set   m.PDF_KUB_PATH = (select p.PDF_KUB_PATH from parsed_ilac_rehberi p where m.BARCODE = p.BARCODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the warning/error is thrown when compiling on this line

```
FETCH c1 INTO  S_KUB , BARCODETEMP,
```

It should be (ending with semi-colon and not comma)

```
FETCH c1 INTO  S_KUB , BARCODETEMP;
```

You can avoid cursor and do this using [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Deneme
IS
    MERGE INTO medicine m
    USING
    (
      SELECT a.PDF_KUB_PATH, a.BARCODE FROM parsed_ilac_rehberi a
    ) v
    ON (m.BARCODE = v.BARCODE)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET m.PDF_KUB_PATH = v.PDF_KUB_PATH

    COMMIT;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'An error was encountered - '
                                    ||SQLCODE||' -ERROR'||SQLERRM);
END;
```

Comment: If possible, handling exceptions in this manner should be avoided at all costs. You're catching _all_ Oracle exceptions and then raising a generic one. It's better to simply not catch exceptions than to use this patter.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version (you don't need MERGE for 1 insert), you don't need redefine exception (as noted by Ben)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Deneme
IS
UPDATE (select a.PDF_KUB_PATH src, m.PDF_KUB_PATH dst
FROM medicine m INNER JOIN parsed_ilac_rehberi a
ON m.BARCODE = a.BARCODE)
SET dst = src;    
END;
```